# I WISH that I could get some clarification in the use of "wish"

Tags: word-usage

I would like to use "wish" to say the following... and then I realize I am not entirely sure how to use wish grammatically

"Do you wish the system to shutdown?"

"Do you wish for the system to shutdown?"

EDIT:

I am **NOT** asking for the *distintion* of meaning between wish and want. In fact I will edit out the want part (it was just to help possible replies). 
I am asking for the correct *usage* of wish.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is the appropriate word here : 'wish' or 'want'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4153/which-is-the-appropriate-word-here-wish-or-want)

Comment: I am asking for the correct use of wish. Not the difference in meaning with want.

Comment: It is hard as the word is in the correct place in the sentences, but it is the wrong word in those sentences, which is why people are confusing your question. "I wish I had already learnt all this English grammar stuff" is a much better example if you don't want everyone confused.

Comment: I agree with @WendyG – I’m having a hard time using the word _wish_ in a sentence like yours. About the best I can muster is: _Do you wish the system were shutdown?_ This is an excellent question, however.

Comment: Also, the verb is separate: **to shut down**.  *Shutdown* is a noun.

Comment: Are you wishing for the system to shutdown because then you can go home early, or wishing for it to be shutdown so you can then perform maintenance?

Comment: Are you trying to create a message that the system woulda display to the user/operator to confirm that they actually want to shut down the system ? Just guessing at the context.

Comment: @laugh Yes, that is what I want. A message asking the user if he wants the system to shut down, but in a polite way

Comment: Why do you think that a message asking if the user **wants**  the system shuts down should not use *want* as verb? *Wish* has a different meaning. (The first sentence that comes to my mind is _I wish I could fly_, and I don't know why I am thinking of that song.)

Answer (score 1):

The differences between *wish* and *want* are discussed in as another answer (mentioned in a comment above). I would refer you to [the Oxford dictionary definition of *wish*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wish) instead. As it explains:

- *Wish to* (with infinitive) is similar to *want to* .
- *Wish something*, *wish for something*, or *wish someone something* (no infinitive) describes a desire or hope that "cannot or probably will not happen" - this is related to *making a wish*.

In the context of asking the user for confirmation of a shutdown, if you specifically wish to use the verb *wish*, I would recommend the phrase

> Do you wish to shutdown the system?

But without an obligation to use *wish*, I would choose something like

> Please confirm system shutdown (y/n)

Answer (score 0):

As nobody else has answered in 6 hours here  is my best attempt at an answer.

Presuming you want the system to shutdown so you can go home early, but it is no way under your control.

> "Do you wish the system would shutdown as well?" Fred said looking at
>   the bored expression on my face.

Unfortunately as my school preferred comprehension and vocabulary over grammar I can't explain why.

But I honestly think you want to use it in the technical sense, in which case the only way to correct your sentence is to use the word want.